# How to fix bash highlighting for left shift?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bash

I have a bash function that does some bit-bashing (no pun intended, and I know the shell is not the best language for that sort of thing), but the syntax highlighter in vim is convinced that this:

```
(( bit = 1<<(left<<2 | middle<<1 | right) ))
```

is the start of a here-document, so everything from that point on is colored as a string literal (except for parameter expansions, of course, since that's clearly an unquoted sentinel).

Is there a simple fix for this I can add to my vimrc, or a plugin that does a better job? I tried bash-support, but it seems a little heavyweight for my needs; I don't want a full-featured Bash IDE, especially not one I have to customize just to get it to *not* add automatic comment prologues to every shell script I create. I just want the colors to be right.

Any suggestions?

The problem is exhibited on MacOS and various Debian-based Linux distros with latest vim (including a freshly-compiled 9.0.1030) and neovim. It doesn't seem to be present in vim before 8.0 or neovim before 0.3.0.

Comment: what filetype are you using?

Comment: I've tried `sh` and `bash`. Same result either way.  Interestingly it's colored correctly if I manually set the ft to `zsh`..

Comment: That *is* interesting. What's more interesting is that for filetype `sh`, I'm having normal text, not string. For `zsh`, I'm getting the latter part as string (zshHereDoc to be exact). (I'm using neovim v8.0.) And at any rate, you/we will have to dig around the syntax regex. That's a boring task.

Comment: I don't think you mean neovim v8.0?  I have vim 8.2.3455 and neovim 0.7.2, both of which exhibit the problem even without any of my configuration files.

Comment: Can confirm on `vim-enhanced-8.2.2637-16.el9_0.3.x86_64`, workaround of `:set filetype=zsh` appears to work

Comment: @computergeek125 Your suggestion solves the problem (by first appearances) on Vim 8.2. Your comment is the answer.

Comment: @markling computergeek125 was just confirming the result I mentioned in my comment above, but glad it also works for you. I guess I should turn it into an answer.

Comment: On reflection I found that it seemed to work for that precise purpose, but otherwise did away with highlighting on other things, e.g. vars, and some reserved words. It was a good quick fix, and perhaps not the answer after all. I have just found that the same lines, written into a script with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang at the top and `syntax=sh`, highlighted without fault.